# Traverse a json object recursively Results in "uncaught syntaxError: Illegal return statement"

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, traversal

I'm trying to navigate through a JSON object for the first time recursively, and the code when running through the debugger appears to work up until it tries to return the object when I have found the groupId that I am looking for. This is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:55)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:954:21)
    at findGroupId (http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5978872e6c1baaa184d2e8ced60239201437139491273/index.html?editors=001:503:21)
    at findGroupId (http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5978872e6c1baaa184d2e8ced60239201437139491273/index.html?editors=001:491:32)
    at findGroupId (http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5978872e6c1baaa184d2e8ced60239201437139491273/index.html?editors=001:491:32)
    at findGroupId (http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5978872e6c1baaa184d2e8ced60239201437139491273/index.html?editors=001:491:32)
    at findGroupId (http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5978872e6c1baaa184d2e8ced60239201437139491273/index.html?editors=001:491:32)
    at findGroupId (http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5978872e6c1baaa184d2e8ced60239201437139491273/index.html?editors=001:491:32)
    at findGroupId (http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/5978872e6c1baaa184d2e8ced60239201437139491273/index.html?editors=001:491:32)
```

Feel free to critique any part of it as it is my first time trying to do this. :)

My sample code is the following:

```
'use strict';

var findGroupId = function (obj, id) {
    var checkForId = function (key, obj) {
        if (key == id) {
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }; 
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
                findGroupId(obj[i], id);
            } else if (Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
                for (var x = 0 ; x <= obj[i].length ; x++) {
                    findGroupId(obj[i], id);
                }
            } else {
                var result = checkForId(obj[i], obj);
                if (result) {
                    debugger;
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
var result = findGroupId(obj, "37078;1");
console.log(result);
```

Here is an executable example: 
http://codepen.io/eaglejs/pen/vOaZgd

Here is the fixed solution thanks to Pablo:
http://codepen.io/eaglejs/pen/QbBKGK

Comment: In your actual environment are you handling this as a promise? I think async may be biting you in the tail here.

Comment: In my environment, it is not a promise, it is just written as a method in my collection (backbone). I've always been taught to code asynchronously, I don't think I even know how to code synchronously haha. Should I use a try/catch or something along those lines? :)

Comment: I put a debugger in where you can call "return obj" in the console and you'll see the error. Even with the 'use strict', it fails silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you arent actually returning anything, You have to return something from all function calls in your code.

The easiest fix would be to store the result and return it if its not undefined.

```
function checkForId(key, obj, id) {
    if (key == id) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
var findGroupId = function (obj, id) {
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
                var myresult = findGroupId(obj[i], id);
                if (myresult)
                    return myresult;
            } else if (Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
                for (var x = 0; x <= obj[i].length; x++) {
                    var myresult = findGroupId(obj[i], id);
                    if (myresult)
                        return myresult;
                }
            } else {
                var result = checkForId(obj[i], obj, id);
                if (result) {
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

modified codepen that works

Note that I also improved a little the findGroupId removing the checkForId  and putting it outside of the "loop" because otherwise you redefine it over and over again.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOjwYW?editors=001

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the issue! I knew it had something to do with adding returns to every function call! I had no idea that I needed to move the checkForId function outside of the findGroupId. Thank you! :D

Comment: Actually you didn't have to move it outside, its just a little optimisation that I've made. The main issue was that you were just calling the function instead of returning the result here: `for (var x = 0 ; x <= obj[i].length ; x++) { findGroupId(obj[i], id);}` and here  `if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
    findGroupId(obj[i], id);}`

Comment: Again thank you so much! I learned a lot! I'll leave this codepen up so people can see it. I created another that shows the correct solution found here: 

http://codepen.io/eaglejs/pen/QbBKGK

I also edited the original post so that people can find it easier.